# VBA Insert Only Added last row

Tags: sql, vba

I have wrapped the SQL Insert statement in the below Do While loop, however it is only inserting the last row from the range to the SQL table. What I'm trying to achieve is each row is copied to the table. So in my example data in excel I have 8 rows, I need to copy all 8 rows to my SQL table. I'm thinking that maybe my loop is wrong or it just needs tweaking but I'm struggling

```
   Do While Sheets("Exposure").Range("B14").Offset(i, 0).Value <> ""
    j = i + 1

    ' Compose the INSERT statement.
    stSQL = "INSERT INTO AH_Exposure " & _
        "(Contract_ID, Location_ID, Country, State, Death_GrpVol, Death_GrpLives, Death_IndVol, Death_IndLives, Disability_GrpVol, Disability_GrpLives, Disability_IndVol, Disability_IndLives) " & _
        " VALUES (" & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("B14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & j & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("C14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("D14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("E14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("F14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("G14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("H14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("I14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("J14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("K14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & Sheets("Exposure").Range("L14").Offset(i, 0).Value & "'" & _
        ")"
    i = i + 1

    Loop
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're composing the statement but there is no code within the loop to actually execute it. Thus it is only the last value in stSQL that is used

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now that I look at the code again, do you know what the code would be? I guess it would be inserted just before the i = i + 1 at the bottom

Comment: Thank you I have just figured this out

Comment: @Carlos80 - you could put it before that line, as long as it appears before "Loop"